# Generating samples from a two-Gaussian mixture in r (code given in MATLAB)

Tags: r, matlab, plot, gaussian, sample

I'm trying to create (in r) the equivalent to the following MATLAB function that will generate n samples from a mixture of N(m1,(s1)^2) and N(m2, (s2)^2) with a fraction, alpha, from the first Gaussian.

I have a start, but the results are notably different between MATLAB and R (i.e., the MATLAB results give occasional values of +-8 but the R version never even gives a value of +-5). **Please help me sort out what is wrong here.** Thanks :-)

For Example:
Plot 1000 samples from a mix of N(0,1) and N(0,36) with 95% of samples from the first Gaussian. Normalize the samples to mean zero and standard deviation one.

**MATLAB**

*function*

```
function y = gaussmix(n,m1,m2,s1,s2,alpha)
y = zeros(n,1);
U = rand(n,1);
I = (U < alpha)
y = I.*(randn(n,1)*s1+m1) + (1-I).*(randn(n,1)*s2 + m2);
```

*implementation*

```
P = gaussmix(1000,0,0,1,6,.95)
P = (P-mean(P))/std(P)
plot(P)
axis([0 1000 -15 15])
hist(P)
axis([-15 15 0 1000])
```

*resulting plot*

[image: plot of randomly generated samples from two Gaussian distributions in MATLAB]

*resulting hist*

[image: histogram of randomly generated samples from two Gaussian distributions in MATLAB]

**R**

```
yn <- rbinom(1000, 1, .95)
s <- rnorm(1000, 0 + 0*yn, 1 + 36*yn)
sn <- (s-mean(s))/sd(s)
plot(sn, xlim=range(0,1000), ylim=range(-15,15))
hist(sn, xlim=range(-15,15), ylim=range(0,1000))
```

*resulting plot*

[image: plot of randomly generated samples from two Gaussian distributions in R]

*resulting hist*

[image: histogram of randomly generated samples from two Gaussian distributions in R]

As always, THANK YOU!

**SOLUTION**

```
gaussmix <- function(nsim,mean_1,mean_2,std_1,std_2,alpha){
   U <- runif(nsim)
   I <- as.numeric(U<alpha)
   y <- I*rnorm(nsim,mean=mean_1,sd=std_1)+
       (1-I)*rnorm(nsim,mean=mean_2,sd=std_2)
   return(y)
}

z1 <- gaussmix(1000,0,0,1,6,0.95)
z1_standardized <- (z1-mean(z1))/sqrt(var(z1))
z2 <- gaussmix(1000,0,3,1,1,0.80)
z2_standardized <- (z2-mean(z2))/sqrt(var(z2))
z3 <- rlnorm(1000)
z3_standardized <- (z3-mean(z3))/sqrt(var(z3))

par(mfrow=c(2,3))
hist(z1_standardized,xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(0,500),
   main="Histogram of 95% of N(0,1) and 5% of N(0,36)",
   col="blue",xlab=" ")
hist(z2_standardized,xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(0,500),
   main="Histogram of 80% of N(0,1) and 10% of N(3,1)",
   col="blue",xlab=" ")
hist(z3_standardized,xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(0,500),
   main="Histogram of samples of LN(0,1)",col="blue",xlab=" ")
##
plot(z1_standardized,type='l',
   main="1000 samples from a mixture N(0,1) and N(0,36)",
   col="blue",xlab="Samples",ylab="Mean",ylim=c(-10,10))
plot(z2_standardized,type='l',
   main="1000 samples from a mixture N(0,1) and N(3,1)",
   col="blue",xlab="Samples",ylab="Mean",ylim=c(-10,10))
plot(z3_standardized,type='l',
  main="1000 samples from LN(0,1)",
   col="blue",xlab="Samples",ylab="Mean",ylim=c(-10,10))
```

Comment: if you think that one of these answers solves your problem you should click on the checkmark to accept whichever one you like best ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems, I think ... (1) your R code is creating a mixture of normal distributions with *standard deviations of 1 and 37*.  (2) By setting `prob` equal to alpha in your `rbinom()` call, you're getting a fraction alpha in the *second* mode rather than the first.  So what you are getting is a distribution that is mostly a Gaussian with sd 37, contaminated by a 5% mixture of Gaussian with sd 1, rather than a Gaussian with sd 1 that is contaminated by a 5% mixture of a Gaussian with sd 6.  Scaling by the standard deviation of the mixture (which is about 36.6) basically reduces it to a standard Gaussian with a slight bump near the origin ...

(The other answers posted here do solve your problem perfectly well, but I thought you might be interested in a diagnosis ...)

A more compact (and perhaps more idiomatic) version of your Matlab `gaussmix` function (I think `runif(n)<alpha` is slightly more efficient than `rbinom(n,size=1,prob=alpha)` )

```
gaussmix <- function(n,m1,m2,s1,s2,alpha) {
    I <- runif(n)<alpha
    rnorm(n,mean=ifelse(I,m1,m2),sd=ifelse(I,s1,s2))
}
set.seed(1001)
s <- gaussmix(1000,0,0,1,6,0.95)
```

Comment: Hrm, I'm not sure what you're talking about with the limits? If I run my code in R without specifications for the axes, it plots from -3 to 4. The MATLAB code also plots within the -15 to 15 limits. I added the scales to better show how off I am. The mixture is normalized to mean=0 and stdev=1.

Comment: You're right that I misdiagnosed originally.  I found the second error.

Answer (score 2):

Not that you asked for it, but the `mclust` package offers a way to generalize your problem to more dimensions and diverse covariance structures.  See `?mclust::sim`.  The example task would be done this way:

```
require(mclust)
simdata = sim(modelName = "V",
              parameters = list(pro = c(0.95, 0.05),
                                mean = c(0, 0),
                                variance = list(modelName = "V", 
                                                d = 1, 
                                                G = 2,
                                                sigmasq = c(0, 36))),
              n = 1000)
plot(scale(simdata[,2]), type = "h")
```

Comment: Thanks! I almost asked a new question specifically about generating data from a mclust model.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote the density and sampling function of a multinomial mixture of normal distributions:

```
dmultiNorm <- function(x,means,sds,weights)
{
  if (length(means)!=length(sds)) stop("Length of means must be equal to length of standard deviations")
  N <- length(x)
  n <- length(means)
  if (missing(weights))
  {
    weights <- rep(1,n)  
  }
  if (length(weights)!=n) stop ("Length of weights not equal to length of means and sds")
  weights <- weights/sum(weights)
  dens <- numeric(N)
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    dens <- dens + weights[i] * dnorm(x,means[i],sds[i])
  }
  return(dens)
}

rmultiNorm <- function(N,means,sds,weights,scale=TRUE)
{
  if (length(means)!=length(sds)) stop("Length of means must be equal to length of standard deviations")
  n <- length(means)
  if (missing(weights))
  {
    weights <- rep(1,n)  
  }
  if (length(weights)!=n) stop ("Length of weights not equal to length of means and sds")

  Res <- numeric(N)
  for (i in 1:N)
  {
    s <- sample(1:n,1,prob=weights)
    Res[i] <- rnorm(1,means[s],sds[s])  
  }
  return(Res)
}
```

With `means` being a vector of means, `sds` being a vector of standard deviatians and `weights` being  a vector with proportional probabilities to sample from each of the distributions. Is this useful to you?

Comment: I think you could probably make the weighting step in your `dmultiNorm` into a matrix multiplication ...

Comment: `rmultiNorm(1000,c(0,0),c(1,36),c(.95,.05))` (after running the code above to get the function) should do what you want I think. `scale` apparently is a stray argument from old code, not sure why I left that in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to do this task:

"For Example: Plot 1000 samples from a mix of N(0,1) and N(0,36) with 95% of samples from the first Gaussian. Normalize the samples to mean zero and standard deviation one."

```
 plot(multG <- c( rnorm(950), rnorm(50, 0, 36))[sample(1000)] , type="h")
 scmulG <- scale(multG)
 summary(scmulG)
 #-----------    
   V1          
 Min.   :-9.01845  
 1st Qu.:-0.06544  
 Median : 0.03841  
 Mean   : 0.00000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.13940  
 Max.   :12.33107
```

[image]