# Function that returns a mixture of probability densities

Tags: r, functional-programming

In R, I would like to create a function which does the following:

```
given vectors of means, variances and weights
create a function which is a mixture of normal distributions
return this function
```

A mixture of normal densities is the sum

```
f(x) = c_1 * N(mu_1,var_1) + ... + c_n * N(mu_n,var_n).
```

What's an easy way of doing this in R?

**edit** 
I figured out a very straightforward, perhaps naive way of doing this:

```
gmix <- function(means,vars,weights){
  n <- length(means)

  f<- function(t) { 
    res <- 0;

    for(i in 1:n) {
      res <- res + weights[i]*dnorm(t,mean=means[i],sd=sqrt(vars[i]))
    }
     return(res)
    }
    return(f)
}
```

I'm no programmer so this might be not a smart way of doing this... If anyone knows a better implementation I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: [**Do these answers from Sacha and/or Ben help?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450007/generating-samples-from-a-two-gaussian-mixture-in-r-code-given-in-matlab)

Comment: Interesting post, and I certainly helps, thanks.